# dijit.form.Select re-appears unpopulated?

Tags: java, javascript, dojo

This is a continuation of an issue I was having yesterday so if it looks familiar, thats why :) It IS a different question tho!

So I have another dijit.form.Select initially created on the page like so;

```
<c:set var="clazzId" value="${verification.clazz.id}" />
<div id="clazzOptions">
    <select id="clazz" name="clazz" style="width:22em" dojoType="dijit.form.Select" maxHeight="140">
        <option value="-1" label="                      " />
        <c:forEach items="${requestScope.clazzes}" var="clazzItem">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${clazzId eq clazzItem.id}">
                    <option value="${clazzItem.id}" selected = "true">${clazzItem.name}</option>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <option value="${clazzItem.id}">${clazzItem.name}</option>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>  
</div>
```

I then have some javascript that I'm trying to use to swap the contents of the div "clazzOptions" depending on the value chosen from a different drop down (not seen here). If its a certain value, replace the div with a text message, if its any other value, re-show the original dijit.form.Select;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var classDropDown;
    var classPhDMessage = "PhD's do not require a Class or Grade";

    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        classDropDown = dojo.byId('clazzOptions').innerHTML;
    });

    function checkForPHD() {
        var awardOption = dijit.byId('qualification').attr('displayedValue');

        if(awardOption == "PhD"){
            dojo.byId('clazzOptions').innerHTML = classPhDMessage;
        } else {
            dojo.byId('clazzOptions').innerHTML = classDropDown;
        }
     }
</script>
```

As you can see I'm trying to capture the innerHTMLof the div as it is when the page loads and then depending on the value chosen in the other drop down (not seen) change between a predefine message and the captured div contents.

The issue is that after the original div contents have been replaced with the message and then the selection changes again away from "PhD" and the original div innerHTML is placed back into the div, the dijit.form.Select re-appears but is completely empty and in fact doesn't appear usable at all? If I remove the dijit.form.Select dojoType and just leave it as a normal select this whole operation works perfectly but I kinda need it to be a dijit.form.Select.

Why won't dijit.form.Select work in this case whereas a normal select does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use innerHTML to add/remove dijits, especially if you're trying to re-use them.

A dijit is a combination of HTML and Javascript and can be thought of as 'more complex' than simply the contents of a specific node.

You have a number of options:

1. Disable your `dijit.form.Select` and add a small note under it (or set it's value) explaining why it's disabled (this is generally a better UI paradigm than removing controls). Depending on your UI this is what I'd try and do
2. Create a `<span>` as a sibling of your `dijit.form.Select` and use CSS to show/hide one of them at a time.

   Obviously you'll still get the value of the `dijit.form.Select` when you submit your form, but because you do server side validation as well as client side validation (I hope :) this won't be a problem
3. Use the `dojo.data` API to create a datastore from your `"${requestScope.clazzes}"` iterator. Use this store when you (programatically) create the `dijit.form.Select`. Keep track of the current value of said `Select` somewhere. When you don't need it, call `yourSelect.destroy()` to properly destroy it, then when you need it again create a new one and set it's value to the saved value from before.

   This seems unnecessarily expensive to me tho.

Comment: I just went with Option 1 in the end, Keep It Simple Stupid!